# What is the exact Font of this H1 and can i use it on Windows?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to Replicate for a test This old Apple Website:
https://web.archive.org/web/20140301004610/http://www.apple.com/

The h1 in question is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiZek.jpg

I Followed the font family that they have been using in the developer tools, but my result is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRPpw.jpg

Looks like the original one is less bold. I've tried everything ( font-size etc) But I can't really make The exactly the same. Any help would be really appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Depending on your browser, might be [font-smoothing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth)

Comment: Did you make sure to actually reference the font correctly? Please share your code regarding that.

Comment: From what I can see, the text on the page you linked to is part of an image...

Comment: Help us help you by posting your code here.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see it's an `img` not a `h1` and the image contains the text:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140301004336im_/http://images.apple.com/home/images/your_verse_title_small.png

Answer (score 0):

I believe the font used is Neue Helvetica Thin.

Answer (score 0):

Companies use to have custom fonts not available for download. However, usually those fonts are not completely new fonts but just some variant of an existing font.

In your special case I was not able to find a font matching your image exactly, either the "a", "e" oder "?" letter are a little different from the picture. (Yes it is a picture rendered, not a font as you pointed out correctly already)

However, **SF Pro Display Thin** might match the font the most. **Helvetica Neue Thin or Helvetica Neue Ultra Thin** are pretty close as well.

Apple Fonts are available at https://developer.apple.com/fonts/ but make sure to meet the license agreements.